# lost key for 76 chevy pickup

Tags: chevrolet, key, pick-up

I would like to know how to stArt my 76 chevy pickup without a key.  The steering column is not locked but the ignition switch will not turn.  It is a four speed standard transmission.  I dont have title or keys for the truck yet, it was basically given to me as a restoration project

Comment: Drop the steering column from its mount, then you can access the ignition switch, un-mount the ign switch, now you can use a small screwdriver to work the switch to start the truck. That or replace the lock cylinder with a new one.